# Why is SELECT COUNT(*) much slower than SELECT * even without WHERE clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a view that has a duration time of ~0.2 seconds when I do a simple `SELECT *` from it, but has a duration time of ~25 seconds when I do simply `SELECT COUNT(*)` from it. What would cause this? It seems like if it takes 0.2 seconds to compute the output data then it could run a simple length calculation on that dataset in a trivial amount of time. MySQL 5.7. Details below.

```
mysql> select count(*) from Lots;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  4136666 |
+----------+
1 row in set (25.29 sec)
```

In MySQL workbench, the following query produces durations like: 0.217 sec

```
select * from Lots;
```

The fetch time is significant given the amount of data, but my understanding is the "Duration" is how long it takes to compute the output dataset of the view.

Definition of Lots view:

```
  select
    lot.*,
    coalesce(overrides.streetNumber, address.streetNumber, lot.rawStreetNumber) as streetNumber,
    coalesce(overrides.street, address.street, lot.rawStreet) as street,
    coalesce(overrides.postalCode, address.postalCode, lot.rawPostalCode) as postalCode,
    coalesce(overrides.city, address.city, lot.rawCity) as city
  from LotsData lot
  left join Address address on address.lotNumber = lot.lotNumber
  left join Override overrides on overrides.lotId = lot.lotNumber
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see how each query is performed.

Comment: I suspect the result of `SELECT *` was cached.

Comment: note that mysql workbench may add a `LIMIT` clause invisibly.  use a client that doesn't lie to you.

Comment: and usually if a view is making queries slow, the easy answer is stop using a view

Comment: @Barmar - The Query Cache usually comes in with sub-millisecond times.  217ms suggests not QC, but appended LIMIT.

Answer (score 1):

The data in VIEW objects isn't materialized. That is, it doesn't exist in any sort of tabular form in your database server. Rather, the server pulls it together from its tables when a query (like your COUNT query) references the VIEW. So, there's no simple metadata hanging around in the server that can satisfy your COUNT query instantaneously. The server has to pull together all your joined tables to generate a row count. It takes a while. Remember, your database server may have other clients concurrently INSERTing or DELETEing rows to one or more of the tables in your view.

It's worse than that. In the InnoDB storage engine, even COUNTing the rows of a table is slow. To achieve high concurrency InnoDB doesn't attempt to store any kind of precise row count. So the database server has to count those rows one-by-one as well. (The older MyISAM storage engine does maintain precise row count metadata for tables, but it offers less concurrency.)

Wise data programmers avoid using COUNT(*) on whole tables or views composed from them in production for those reasons.

The real question is why your `SELECT * FROM view` is so fast. It's unlikely that your database server can compose and deliver a 4-megarow view from its JOINs in less than a second, nor is it likely that Workbench can absorb that many rows in that time.  Like @ysth said, many GUI-based SQL client programs, like Workbench and HeidiSQL, sometimes silently append something like `LIMIT 1000` to interactive operations calling for the display of whole tables or views. You might look for evidence of that.